# Notification ping from backend using Web sockets and tornado

Tags: python, websocket, tornado, mqtt

I am new to web-sockets. I am using tornado/python for my back-end and written the following code.

```
class BaseWebSocketHandler(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    """Base Class to establish an websocket connection."""

    def open(self):
        """Opening the web socket connection."""
        self.write_message('Connection Established.')

    def on_message(self, message):
        """On message module send the response."""
        pass

    def on_close(self):
        """Close the connection."""
        self.write_message('bye')

class MeterInfo(BaseWebSocketHandler):
    """Establish an websocket connection and send meter readings."""

    def on_message(self, message):
        """On message module send to the response."""
        self.write_message({'A': get_meter_reading()})
```

My JavaScript code is like the following,

```
var meter = new WebSocket("ws://"+window.location.host+"/socket/meterstatus/");
meter.onopen = function() {
      $('#meter-well').text('Establishing connection...');
};
meter.onmessage = function (evt) {
     var data = JSON.parse(evt.data)
     var text = "<div class='meter'><h2>" + data.A +"</h2></div>";
     $('#meter-pre').html(text);
};
meter.onclose = function (evt) {
     console.log(JSON.parse(evt.data))
     $('#meter-pre').append('\n'+evt.data);
};
window.setInterval(function(){ meter.send('') }, 100);
```

I am making a blank web-socket request request to the back-end every 100 millisecond. this seems a very bad solution to me. Is there any better way to do it without making multiple send() to the back-end and only notifying the user only on any changes in the meter reading?

Also i have gone through MQTT protocol to do this in a better way, can someone suggest how can i implement that?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here, do you want to replace all that code with MQTT?

Comment: @hardillb i want a better solution so that i will not need to make the send() to server every 100 milliseconds.

Comment: So what have you tried already, we'll help you fix something that doesn't work, but unlikely to write it all for you?

Comment: @hardillb as i said what i have done is working and i am new to websockets. I want a better solution to ping the browser from the backend without requesting the backend multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You almost found the solution to your issue here:

```
class MeterInfo(BaseWebSocketHandler):
"""Establish an websocket connection and send meter readings."""

   def on_message(self, message):
       """On message module send to the response."""
       self.write_message({'A': get_meter_reading()})
```

As you could notice tornado needs some event to ping client through `write_message` method. You are using new message from client as such event, try to change to simple timeout call as event, like this:

```
# BaseWebSocketHandler removed, because we need to track all opened
# sockets in the class. You could change this later.
class MeterInfo(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    """Establish an websocket connection and send meter readings."""
    opened_sockets = []
    previous_meter_reading = 0

    def open(self):
    """Opening the web socket connection."""
        self.write_message('Connection Established.')
        MeterInfo.opened_sockets.append(self)

    def on_close(self):
        """Close the connection."""
        self.write_message('bye')
        MeterInfo.opened_sockets.remove(self)

    @classmethod
    def try_send_new_reading(cls):
        """Send new reading to all connected clients"""
        new_reading = get_meter_reading()

        if new_reading == cls.previous_meter_reading:
            return

        cls.previous_meter_reading = new_reading

        for socket in cls.opened_sockets:
            socket.write_message({'A': new_reading})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # add this after all set up and before starting ioloop
    METER_CHECK_INTERVAL = 100  # ms
    ioloop.PeriodicCallback(MeterInfo.try_send_new_reading,
                            METER_CHECK_INTERVAL).start()
    # start loop
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Check out [tornado.ioloop documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback) for more about PeriodicCallback and other options.

If you want to use tornado to MQTT protocol, it's not possible with tornado. You could try [emqtt server](https://github.com/emqtt/emqttd) for example, but this is actual server, not framework to write apps, so IMHO it would be more comprehensive that ping through web socket with tornado.

Comment: This a really very good approach to do a Periodic call back and check, But not an answer to my question. I need the front-end js code to notify the user instead of how i am doing right now. Currently i am using setInterval of 100 milliseconds to check the status is there any better way so that i will not need to do that.

Comment: @binayr could you please give more info about your `meter` abstraction? Am I understand you correctly now, do you need to send a message to front end from back end only when there is new meter data?

Comment: @binayr than it could be easy modified to get value from `meter`, compare to previous one and send to front end only in case of difference. Check out edit.